# Error 405 when trying PUT Method (Jersey / Java): Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, json, jersey, put

I am having a problem with the Jersey PUT method. I simply want to add a String (MediaType APPLICATION_JSON) to localhost:8080/testtest. But when trying this with the line

```
service.path("testtest")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .put(String.class, "{\"firstName\":\""+firstName+"\",\"lastName\":\""+lastName+"\"}");
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT http://localhost:8080/testtest returned a response status of 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Here is the whole code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;

@Path("testtest")
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
        test();
    }

    private static void test() throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/");
        server.start();
        WebResource service = Client.create().resource("http://localhost:8080/");
        String firstName = "First Name";
        String lastName = "Last Name";

        service.path("testtest")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .put(String.class, "{\"firstName\":\""+firstName+"\",\"lastName\":\""+lastName+"\"}");
        // Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: PUT http://localhost:8080/testtest returned a response status of 405 Method Not Allowed

        System.out.println(service.path("testtest").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
        server.stop(0);
    }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your service method doesn't have `@PUT` annotation. Post your service code for better diagnose.